# Can the lenses for the Pentax K-r camera be used on the Pentax K-70?

Tags: old-lenses

Can the lenses for the Pentax K-r camera be used on the Pentax K-70 camera?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both are crop Pentax K-mount dSLRs. They can use the same lenses.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Pentax K-70 which would prevent you from using same lenses K-r accepts. Last time Pentax introduced incompatibility with old lenses is when they removed aperture sensing which made it impossible to use A-lenses.